# Core Location returns nil when asked for location

Tags: swift, core-location

My private constant in my Custom class:

```
private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

in `viewDidLoad()` I call the method:

```
private func setupLocationManager() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

But when I ask about location at some time later:

```
println("-----\(locationManager.location)")
```

I get:

```
-----nil
```

Where is the problem? I run this on device. My app is allowed to use location...

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to get location that way because getting location can take some time (for more information see [GPS TTFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_fix)). Since your location manager already has a delegate you must get location in `didUpdateLocations` delegate method. Also always make sure you have the permission to use location before calling `startUpdatingLocation`

```
private func setupLocationManager() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways{

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }else{
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!){

    println(manager.location)

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse || status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways {

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }
}
```

Comment: How long can I wait for this? I add your method as a delegate method, but nothing happens.

Comment: It depends on a few factors. Are you connected to WiFi? Do you have clear view on the sky? Is your device GPS working correctly?

Comment: yes, connected to wifi, clear sky indeed, gps working correctly, I use it in other applications like Maps

Comment: not working... what about sth keys inside `info.plist`. Required capabilities? I did it also, but still not working

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk can you try it on different device ? Or try uninstalling  app first then run it again